# can't enter recovery mode after flashing resurrection remix v5.8.5 android 7.1 in Lenovo vibe k4 note

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot, android-pc, resurrection-remix-os

recently I have been trying out new roms. When I flashed resurrection remix v5.8.5 on my device (Lenovo vibe k4 note) via TWRP recovery, after that the room was working fine, but magisk came pre-installed, which, when I open, gives an error: "magisk manager has stopped working". So I decided to change to another rom. but I can't boot into recovery menu after flashing resurrection remix os. when I try to boot into recovery, it directly boots the system. And when I power it off, after an hour or two, it automatically powers on and boots the system. I would be grateful if someone helps me. Thank you

Comment: uninstall + re-install [Magisk Manager apk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD)

Comment: I can uninstall magisk, but can't reinstall cuz I can't enter recovery mode

Comment: i am talking about *Magisk **Manager** apk* only (not about *Magisk zip*)